# Indoor Myer Lemon Tree Yellowing

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, fruit-trees

I do not see any obvious reason for the yellowing leaves.  There are no visible pests or scale. It is currently limited to 2 or 3 leaves although the yellowing started suddenly and one has already fallen off.

I do not believe I am over or under watering.  I have a moisture meter that is never above half way and I usually wait till it is down to 2 (dry). It is indoor in a pot with a drain hole.

[image: Lemon tree with some yellowed leaves]

Comment: It could be that those leaves are old and need to be discarded.

Comment: That would be nice.  It would mean I'm worrying about nothing.  I only pause because A - the tree is new from last fall, and B - they seem to be smaller (newer?) leaves.